# beeline cannot connect to hive2server

Tags: hive

Enter username for jdbc:hive2://localhost:10001/default: 
Enter password for jdbc:hive2://localhost:10001/default: 
17/08/19 09:25:14 [main]: WARN jdbc.HiveConnection: Failed to connect to localhost:10001
Could not open connection to the HS2 server. Please check the server URI and if the URI is correct, then ask the administrator to check the server status.
Error: Could not open client transport with JDBC Uri: jdbc:hive2://localhost:10001/default: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused (Connection refused) (state=08S01,code=0)
Beeline version 2.3.0 by Apache Hive
beeline> show tables;
No current connection
beeline>

I tried to changing the xml properties also but struck in same place

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are connecting to the wrong port number:

```
 jdbc:hive2://localhost:10001
```

If you did not change the hive-site.xml, thrift port is 10000. If you still want to connect to 10001 which is used by thrift on Http, you need to add "transportMode=http" in your beeline connection string.